# Draw male and female gender symbols in iOS

Tags: ios

Does anyone know how to programmatically draw the male and female gender signs in iOS like the ones below?

[image: Gender symbols]

Comment: This topic should be closed as to he or she does not state as to what the exact issue is in making those drawings.  Besides, making those drawings isn't really a programming question.

Comment: You can look into CoreGraphics.

Comment: Use the female and male characters in a `UILabel` and use a large font like System 200 `"♀"` `"♂"`.

Comment: Just use the unicode character's for these

Comment: unicode character's are a good idea, but we want to be able to draw them so we can have just an outline of the symbols or fill them in like the examples above.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An example for drawing the female symbol. **First**, make a Layer using `UIBezierPath` to draw it:

```
import UIKit

class FemaleLayer: CAShapeLayer {

    override var frame: CGRect {
        didSet{
            self.draw()
        }
    }

    private func draw() {
        self.lineWidth = 20.0
        self.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        self.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        let sideLength = fmin(self.frame.width, self.frame.height)
        let circlesRadius = (sideLength / 2.0 - self.lineWidth) * 0.6
        let circleCenterY = self.bounds.midY * 0.8

        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x:self.bounds.midX, y:circleCenterY), radius: circlesRadius, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)

        let circleBottomY = circleCenterY + circlesRadius
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.midX, y: circleBottomY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.midX, y: circleBottomY + circlesRadius))
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.midX * 0.6, y: circleBottomY + circlesRadius * 0.5))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.midX * 1.4, y: circleBottomY + circlesRadius * 0.5))

        self.path = path.cgPath
    }
}
```

**Then** use it by adding the layer to a UIView:

```
let femaleLayer = FemaleLayer()
femaleLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
self.view.layer.addSublayer(femaleLayer)
```

The **final** result:
[image]

**Updated**, for male:

```
class MaleLayer: CAShapeLayer {
    override var frame: CGRect {
        didSet{
            self.draw()
        }
    }

    private func draw() {
        self.lineWidth = 20.0
        self.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        self.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        let sideLength = fmin(self.frame.width, self.frame.height)
        let circlesRadius = (sideLength / 2.0 - self.lineWidth) * 0.6
        let circleCenterX = self.bounds.midX * 0.9
        let circleCenterY = self.bounds.midY * 1.2

        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x:circleCenterX, y:circleCenterY), radius: circlesRadius, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)

        let circleRightTopX = circleCenterX + circlesRadius * 0.686
        let circleRightTopY = circleCenterY - circlesRadius * 0.686
        let lineLength = circlesRadius * 0.7
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: circleRightTopX, y: circleRightTopY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: circleRightTopX + lineLength, y: circleRightTopY - lineLength))
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: circleRightTopX, y: circleRightTopY - lineLength))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: circleRightTopX + lineLength + self.lineWidth / 2.0, y: circleRightTopY - lineLength))
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: circleRightTopX + lineLength, y: circleRightTopY - lineLength))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: circleRightTopX + lineLength , y: circleRightTopY))

        self.path = path.cgPath
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Just a minor (?) thing... The code you provided should perhaps be named `FemaleLayer` :-)

Comment: Hahaha, stupid mistake! Thanks for indicating that! Answer updated.